# Socket io - Wrong socket address calling

Tags: javascript, socket.io, rancher

I have the following code on my **static client side**:

**socket.io.js file calling**:

```
<script src="https://rancher.mysite.com/mymodule/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

**JS File content:**

```
var socket = io.connect('https://rancher.mysite.com/', {
    'path':'/mymodule/socket.io'
});

socket.on('mymodulefunction', function (msg) {
    /// Do something (it doesn't call)
});
```

But socket.io tries to establish the connection with a different address. I can see this on browser developer tools and the address that he is trying to call in "Network" tab is: "`https://rancher.mysite.com/socket.io`" instead of "`https://rancher.mysite.com/mymodule/socket.io`".

Please, what am I doing wrong? I'm stuck in this problem for hours...

Comment: Is this your client side code or server side code ? Could you please provide code from both client side and server side that would be much helpful in debugging your problem ?

Comment: What's your `<script>` tag for loading socket.io in the web page?  And, is your server configured to respond at `/mymodule/socket.io`.

Comment: @VarunArya this code is from the client side (static pages). I will provide the codes.